# C# How split a string containing numbers in array

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

HI i have a string like this:

```
string test = "1Hello World  2I'm a newbie 33The sun is big 176The cat is black";
```

i want to split the string and put in an array like this:

```
1 Hello World
2 I'm a newbie 
33 The sun is big 
176 The cat is black
```

The result could be in a String[], ArrayList, List or Linq

Added what i tried but its not working..

```
 ArrayList oArrayList = new ArrayList();
 Regex oRegex = new Regex(@"\d+");
 Match oMatch = oRegex.Match(test);
 int last = 0;

 while (oRegex.Match(test).Success)
 {
     oArrayList.Add(oMatch.Value + " " + test.Substring(last, oMatch.Index));
     last = oMatch.Index;
     test = test.Remove(0, oMatch.Index);
     oMatch = oRegex.Match(test);
 }
```

Comment: I hope you like regular expressions, because I have a feeling some will show up shortly...

Comment: "The result could be in a String[], ArrayList, List or Linq"  Sounds like a homework question

Comment: May not be homework, it also could be XY problem of "how to parse result of `node.InnerXml` (`ToString()` of some other well defined format/object tree)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Regular expressions would be one way, or a more verbose route would be flipping through the char arrays and trying to Parse the characters into doubles....many ways to do this homework...

Comment: Actually is not homework, is a project where i trying to parse a huge file from an old yk2 project, i started make smaller test but my head is burnout at this hour :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
string test = "1Hello World  2I'm a newbie 33The sun is big 176The cat is black";

Regex regexObj = new Regex(@"(\d+)([^0-9]+)", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
Match match = regexObj.Match(test);
while (match.Success) 
{
  string numPart = match.Group[1].Value;
  string strPart = match.Group[2].Value;
  match = match.NextMatch();
}
```

Output :

[image: Regex Output]

Comment: I tried this solution and It worked!

Answer (score 0):

Quite simple to be honest

```
 string test = "1Hello World  2I'm a newbie 33The sun is big 176The cat is black";
 var tmp = Regex.Split(test,@"\s(?=\d)");
```

tmp will be a string array

Comment: Nice option but in the result there is no space between the decimal and following text

Comment: its to capture the space before the decimal. did you even try running it in sample console application? if you want space or there is no space before decimal, you can modify regex a little to get what you want but this is the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

Given the input string `test`, you can use `Regex.Split` to split the string on the decimal boundaries.  Add the space between the number and text for each element requires calling `Regex.Match` on each element to obtain the desired formatting:

```
var r = Regex.Split(test, @"(?<=\D)(?=\d)") // split at each boundary 
                                            // between a non-digit (\D)
                                            // and digit (\d).
            .Select(a=>Regex.Match(a, @"(\d+)(.*)").Result("$1 $2"));
                                           // ^ insert a space between
                                           // decimal and following text
```

The result is an `IEnumerable<string>` that can be processed as needed in Linq.